# How to fix AccessDenied Error when accessing KnownFolders.MediaServerDevices?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to build a simple music player for PC / Xbox One that uses DLNA as media sources, but I keep getting an AccessDenied error.

I've imported `Windows.Storage`, and I've enabled the Music Library capability in the App Manifest.
Trying to assign / access `KnownFolders.MediaServerDevices` throws the AccessDenied error. 
From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders.mediaserverdevices) doc, I should only need any of the Music / Picture / Video library dependencies to use `MediaServerDevices`, but enabling any combination of capabilities doesn't seem to work.

```cs
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        StorageFolder MediaServerDevices;
        MediaServerDevices = KnownFolders.MediaServerDevices;
    }
```

This should assign the StorageFolder to `MediaServerDevices`, instead it throws:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  HResult=0x80070005
  Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaServiceDevice` folder collects files of the specified type on the current device, not just music library or other multimedia folders. For mobile phones, it works. But for the PC, it involves access to other folders. So it’s not enough to just get the permissions of the music library.

If you want it to work on a PC, you need to get a wider range of file permissions.

Open `Package.appxmanifest` with code, add the namespace and new `Capability`:

```xml
<Package
  ... 
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

  <Capabilities>
    ...
    <uap:Capability Name="musicLibrary"/>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess"/>
  </Capabilities>

</Package>
```

`broadFileSystemAccess` is the key to access the `MediaServiceDevice`.

This is a restricted capability. Access is configurable in **Settings > Application**. Find your application and open the **advanced options**.

Open `File System`.

At this time you can access the `MediaServiceDevice` folder on your PC.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Yep this worked, thanks! Will this also work on Xbox, or does that require some other permission?

Comment: Sorry, I can't give a definitive answer due to the lack of XBOX devices. But I think it is work

Comment: @mantecademani Unfortunately XBOX will never support broadFileSystemAccess. So actually I don't think this will work on XBOX.